# how should i convert subtracted minutes to unix timestamp

Tags: python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
# how should do this
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
tstamp1 = datetime.strptime('2017-11-30 10:15:00', fmt)
tstamp2 = datetime.strptime('2017-11-30 10:30:00', fmt)
if tstamp1 > tstamp2:
    td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
else:
    td = tstamp2 - tstamp1
td_mins = int(round(td.total_seconds() / 60))
print('The difference is approx. %s minutes' % td_mins)
```

> The difference is approx. 15 minutes

Comment: highlight your code and press ctrl-k

Comment: how should i convert this program  into unix timestamp